# Expansion of dataset based on few constraints

Tags: python, r, pandas, numpy

**EDIT :**

I have a dataframe with the following fields,

```
I_Code Date_1   Date_2  Count real_Count
4   01/09/2019  02/08/2019  112 1
4   01/09/2019  03/08/2019  178 3
1   01/09/2019  04/08/2019  174 6
4   01/09/2019  04/08/2019  174 6
1   01/09/2019  05/08/2019  194 8
4   01/09/2019  05/08/2019  194 8
1   01/09/2019  06/08/2019  195 8
2   01/09/2019  06/08/2019  195 8
4   01/09/2019  07/08/2019  208 10
1   01/09/2019  08/08/2019  183 14
2   01/09/2019  08/08/2019  183 14
4   01/09/2019  08/08/2019  183 14
1   01/09/2019  09/08/2019  213 17
4   01/09/2019  09/08/2019  213 17
1   01/09/2019  10/08/2019  213 14
```

**real_count represents the count of date_2 in the dataframe and count column here refers to the frequency count of the date_2 that I want to achieve in the expansion.** I want to expand the dataframe such that date_2 appears to the total number of count. There are multiple entries for date_2 which are constraint to date_1 and I_code.

```
1   01/09/2019  08/08/2019  183
2   01/09/2019  08/08/2019  183
4   01/09/2019  08/08/2019  183
```

Here the date_2 are same but I_code are different.

Example :

lets say that date_2 = 08/08/2019 has a total of 3 entries. then while expanding, we need to get 183 entries in the dataframe with each entry having equal entries i.e. 183/3.

Can anyone help.

Comment: Why the `R` *and* `Python` code tags?

Comment: @MauritsEvers to achieve the dataset generation either R or python are best languages available.

Comment: What I was trying to say was that multi-codetag questions are often not very popular around SO. They may come across as ["gimme teh codez"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108551/what-site-to-use-if-you-have-a-gimme-teh-codez-question) requests, lacking any genuine attempt from your side, and can frequently be considered (and closed) as too broad. It's best to (1) focus on one coding language and (2) provide some form of code attempt to demonstrate your own effort.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.max(axis=1)` over the results of `.nunique()` to get the maximum number of unique values (across all other columns) for every value of **Date_2**.

Then give the resulting Series a name and join it back with the original dataframe.

```
df.join(df.groupby('Date_2').nunique().max(axis=1).rename('Date_2_Count'), on='Date_2')

I_Code      Date_1      Date_2  Count  real_Count  Date_2_Count
     4  01/09/2019  02/08/2019    112           1             1
     4  01/09/2019  03/08/2019    178           3             1
     1  01/09/2019  04/08/2019    174           6             2
     4  01/09/2019  04/08/2019    174           6             2
     1  01/09/2019  05/08/2019    194           8             2
     4  01/09/2019  05/08/2019    194           8             2
     1  01/09/2019  06/08/2019    195           8             2
     2  01/09/2019  06/08/2019    195           8             2
     4  01/09/2019  07/08/2019    208          10             1
     1  01/09/2019  08/08/2019    183          14             3
     2  01/09/2019  08/08/2019    183          14             3
     4  01/09/2019  08/08/2019    183          14             3
     1  01/09/2019  09/08/2019    213          17             2
     4  01/09/2019  09/08/2019    213          17             2
     1  01/09/2019  10/08/2019    213          14             1
```

Comment: How does this help in expanding the dataset?

Comment: @user3759616 If this wasn't the result you're looking for, it might well be that I did not understand your question properly. Maybe you should attempt to clarify your question and perhaps include an example of the output you're looking for.